# How do avoid building context again if building and destroying is expensive?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

If building and destroying context is heavy, how do I detect that I already have the context and do not need to build it again ? In other words I want the nested context 2 to do nothing.

I may need to need to call the context mutiple times inside a loop, can I put the whole loop inside a `with` clause, and then somehow the context inside the loop knows they are already inside a context, then skip building the context as if the inner `with` clause having no effect ? ( I want to completely skip context 2 in the following example )

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def myContext(i):

    print 'build context', i

    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print 'exiting context',i

def func():
    print 'call func'

with myContext(1):

    print 'outside'

    with myContext(2):
        func()
```

code output:

```
build context 1
outside
build context 2
call func
exiting context 2
exiting context 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It might make sense to use a context manager class that is a singleton, rather than using the `contextmanager` decorator on a function. This isn't fundamentally different than kennytm's answer using a global, but my version hides the global state in a class variable rather than a regular global variable.

```
class MyContext(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, i):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(cls, MyContext).__new__(cls, i)
            cls._instance.depth = 0
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __enter__(self):
        self.depth += 1
        if self.depth == 1:
            self.some_expensive_value = expensive_calculation(self.i)
        return self       # or maybe return self.some_expensive_value?

    def __exit__(self, exec_type, exec_value, traceback):
        self.depth -= 1
        if self.depth == 0:
            self.expensive_value.close()   # clean up value if necessary
```

This approach is not thread-safe, though you could probably make it so by adding a lock that you hold around the changes and checks of `self.depth`. The expensive calculation is only run for the outermost of any number of nested calls to the context manager.

Answer (score 1):

I combined @Blckknght's answer with [Method 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/2052889) from [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python), using metaclass.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from functools import wraps
import time

class Singleton(ABCMeta):
    _instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(cls, "_instance") or cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


class ContextDecorator(object):

    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self._built = False
        self._contextExists = False

    @abstractmethod
    def _build(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _destory(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def clear_singleton(cls):
        cls._instance = None

    def __enter__(self):
        if not self._built:
            self._build()
            self._built = True
            print 'call _build first time'
        else:
            print 'skip _build'
            self._contextExists = True

        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, val, traceback):
        if not self._contextExists:
            self._destory()
            self.clear_singleton()
            # self._contextExists=False
            print 'call _destory first time'
        else:
            print 'skip _destory'
            self._contextExists = False

    def __call__(self, f):
        self.function = f

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            with self:
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kw)
                except:
                    raise
        return wrapper


class CustomContext(ContextDecorator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomContext, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _build(self):
        pass

    def _destory(self):
        pass




print 'context managere test'

with CustomContext():
    for i in range(3):
        with CustomContext():
            time.sleep(0.01)


print '-' * 10
print 'decorator test'


@CustomContext()
@CustomContext()
def test():
    print 'in side test func'


test()
```

And the output

```
context managere test
call _build first time
skip _build
skip _destory
skip _build
skip _destory
skip _build
skip _destory
call _destory first time
----------
decorator test
call _build first time
skip _build
in side test func
skip _destory
call _destory first time
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global reference count:

```
_my_context_call_count = 0

@contextmanager
def my_context(i):
    global _my_context_call_count

    if _my_context_call_count == 0:
        print 'build context', i
    _my_context_call_count += 1

    try:
        yield

    finally:
        _my_context_call_count -= 1
        if _my_context_call_count == 0:
            print 'exiting context', i
```

(Note that this is *not thread-safe*, but it doesn't matter if your program is single-threaded.)